WPS Office and Synaptic
I'm trying to install WPS in Ubuntu 24.04 by using Synaptic.
I've tried to search by all the filtres and writing all names (WPS, wps-office, WPS Office..).
Do i need to install a repository? Am i writing the wrong name?
Thank you beforehand.

24.04 sorry. I've written It wrong

Just follow the official the official instructions: https://www.wps.com/blog/how-to-install-wps-office-on-ubuntu/

Thank you for your answer, but it's mandatory to do It by Synaptic. It is homework from highschool.

You need to create a local repository.

I’m voting to close this question because it is homework help request.

Did you try searching for wps in the App Center?

Software is found in public repositories when its open source code; WPS Office is closed-source, and thus to be inside a repository/store it'll need permission of the owner OR be in a repository created by the owner (ie. they control how you download/install it).  I do see wps-office available in the Ubuntu Snapstore (https://snapcraft.io/wps-office) that you appear to want to use a package manager which is limited to deb based software found in repositories; thus are limited to packages provided in that format in that way.

Thank you so much, guiverc!! I sent an e-mail to my teacher, telling to him what you said. He answered me this morning saying that he was wrong, and it's not possible to do It in the way he requested.  Thank you again!
